# Duplicate ID when inserting

Tags: php, postgresql, orm, silverstripe

I have a function on my website that creates multiple requests for insertion into the database. I've tested for a while and haven't come across this issue but it may be because of more users on the system now.

I'm getting a duplicate key error when running an insert on the DB. I don't believe it's an issue with the code, as I'm just creating a new entry. From previous investigation I believe, on a PostgreSQL db at least, the ID is not an auto incremented one but rather something that is set from the ORM. Could a race condition cause two identical ID's to be attempted to be inserted into the DB?

Comment: What's your ORM auto-increment strategy? Could you provide a model/entity?

Comment: I don't really know, the ORM is SilverStripes built in one and then I have a module loaded on top of it to provide PostgreSQL support. I've looked through the PostgreSQL module and I don't think the auto-increment is in there. I'm now looking through the framework but it's not small.

Comment: So from what I can tell it creates an entry with just the "Created" field filled in, and this creates an ID. So I guess this is a standard auto increment. However, it then queries the db with `SELECT last_value FROM "Table_ID_seq"` with a seperate query. It then updates the columns that actually need updating. Couldn't this create a race condition in a multi server environment where two new records are created, the ID is returned of the last one created and both update that record, leaving one blank record and one record basically lost?

Comment: Yes, it's a very weird way to do auto-increment. Calling `nextval` on `Table_ID_seq` is much more reliable due to MVCC nature of a sequence. I guess you found your problem.

Comment: :/ I doubt I'd run into issues in most of my code however this particular function is spammed outside my control. If a fair number of people are in this area of the system it would start to be highly likely this scenario could occur.

Comment: [Docs](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/model/data_model_and_orm/) says: _When a new record is created, SilverStripe does not use the database's built-in auto-numbering system. Instead, it will generate a new ID by adding 1 to the current maximum ID._ I think you can [extend](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/model/extending_dataobjects/) DataObject's class and make your changes to call `nextval` instead of builtin mechanism

Comment: Might be a bit different with the PostgreSQL one? I logged the database queries and found the above queries and ran through them step by step on the db.

Comment: I think the principle is the same. `SELECT last_value FROM "Table_ID_seq"` gets last id from table and SilverTripes increments it somewhere. But IMHO this is wrong, getting last_value this way will bypass the MVCC nature of sequence, like I said. SilverStripes should do it this way to maintain compatibility with many RDBMS.